# Setting an object property to undefined

Tags: javascript

On Chrome's and Node's console, I assigned the property of an object to have the value of `undefined`.

```
const foo = {
  bar: undefined
};
```

When I evaluate `foo` again, I expected it to give me an empty object (`{}`), but it returns with:

```
{
  bar: undefined
}
```

Are there any differences between `{ bar: undefined }` and `{}`?

The reason I am asking is that this difference is failing my tests - I am expecting the result to be `{}`, but it's failing because the actual response is `{ bar: undefined }`.

If it was `{ bar: null }` I'd understand, since `null` is an actual value. But my understanding is that `undefined` means the property is undefined and thus not even a value.

Comment: undefined is a value. you could use `delete` operator.

Comment: "_Are there any differences between { bar: undefined } and {}?_" Yes, one is an empty object and the other is an object with 1 property with a value of undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a difference. `{ bar: undefined }` has a property called `bar` with the value `undefined`, while `{ }` has no property named bar.

`'bar' in { bar: undefined } === true`

`null` and `undefined` are two different things but they are both values. I think your confusion stems from the fact that accessing a non-existent property also evaluates to `undefined`. I.e. `({}).bar === undefined`.

However it is also valid to have an object with a property that does exist, but has the value `undefined`, and there are differences between those objects. As others have stated, you can `delete` a property from an object with the `delete` operator.

Comment: If it was `{ bar: null }` I'd understand, but I thought `undefined` means the property is _undefined_ and thus not even a value.

Comment: @dayuloli `null` and `undefined` are two different things but they are both values. I think your confusion stems from the fact that accessing a non-existent property also evaluates to `undefined`, EG. `({}).bar === undefined`. However it is also valid to have an object with a property that does exist, but has the value undefined, and there are differences between those objects. As others have stated, you can delete a property from an object with the [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator.

Comment: @dayuloli The delete operator is the way to go if you want to remove a property from an object, rather than setting its value to `undefined`.

Comment: "I think your confusion stems from the fact that accessing a non-existent property also evaluates to `undefined`" <--- this is the source of my confusion yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes. For the first one you have defined property with name `bar`, but it's value is `undefined`, property exists. For the second one you have no property with name `bar`.

You can look at this example. Calling `hasOwnProperty` on object returns the result for the `bar` property. The property `bar` for `foo1` exists and it does not depends on the properties value.

```js
const foo1 = {
  bar: undefined
};

const foo2 = { };

console.log(foo1.hasOwnProperty('bar'));
console.log(foo2.hasOwnProperty('bar'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a difference between the two. `{}` is an object that is empty, while `{ bar: undefined }` is an object with a property `bar` that is undefined.

Note: I see your comments to the other answer. Yes, `bar` property is undefined, but it still exists. There is a difference between a variable or property being undefined or to not exist. Take this example:

```js
var x;
console.log(x);
```

You will get `undefined` as a result, but can you say that the variable `x` doesn't exist? Of course it does exist. The same goes with the `bar` property, it exists and that makes the object different from an empty object `{}`.

So when you assign a property to `undefined`, you only remove its value, but the property stays. When you use `delete`, you remove the property itself and that's the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `delete` operator to delete a property entirely (so that `hasOwnProperty()`, `for in`, `get*PropertyDescritor()`, etc don't see it).

Answer (score -2):

undefined is a type of data, if you spend undefined or null the property bar will always be equal to what you spent and not a empty.

If what you need is an empty object you can do this:

```
const foo = {
  bar: new Object(null); // or empty, or false
};

or 

const foo = {
  bar: {}
};
```

Check in your console this:

```
({} === undefined); // this return false
(new Object() === undefined); // this return false
```